# Which Node APIs are included in electron?

Tags: electron

I am working on an electron app and was wondering which APIs from Node are included in Electron and if there are any differences.

For example, I know that `fs` is included, but I am wondering about other APIs like `util.promisify`. I haven’t found anything in the docs about the supported APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electron actually **is** a node.js app so the full node API is available from the used version. It is pretty much always the most recent version ([at least in one month](https://electron.atom.io/docs/faq/#when-will-electron-upgrade-to-latest-nodejs))   but you can check it with

`process.versions`

in any Electron app